# How can I get a grayscale effect in Kubuntu 18.04 using KWin?

Tags: kubuntu, kwin

How can I use KWin to obtain a grayscale effect in Kubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Murat Çileli](https://gitlab.com/murat.cileli) has developed 
[KWin Grayscale Effect](https://github.com/murat-cileli/kwin-grayscale-effect) which, according to [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/9ghxzp/kwin_grayscale_effect/) is

> a fullscreen, configurable grayscale effect for KWin / KDE

If you want this effect,

- [Download the tar](https://gitlab.com/murat.cileli/kwin-grayscale-effect/-/archive/master/kwin-grayscale-effect-master.tar.gz) and extract it.
- Run `sudo cp -r kwin4_effect_grayscale /usr/share/kwin/effects`
- Run `sudo cp kwin4_effect_grayscale.desktop /usr/share/kservices5/kwin`
- And edit the [Plugins] section of `~/.config/kwinrc` to have `kwin4_effect_grayscaleEnabled=true` on its own line. In case the [Plugins] section is missing from your `kwinrc`, just add it.

To test it for the first time, open `System Settings` > `Desktop Behavior`. In there, open `Desktop Effects`. You should see `Grayscale` in the `Appearance` section. Toggle it a couple of times, and you'll see the grayscale effect at work.

**Grayscale off:**

[image: Grayscale off]

**Grayscale on:**

[image: Grayscale on]

Further configuration is possible. From the gitlab link:

A configuration file should be placed in `/usr/share/kwin/effects/kwin4_effect_grayscale/contents/config/main.xml`.

And available parameters are:

- ApplyInactiveWindowsOnly (boolean) : Effect applies to inactive windows only if it's set true.
- ExcludePanels (boolean) : Effect does not apply to panels if it's set true.
- EffectStrength (integer): Effect strength by percentage (%).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this walk-through. For some reason, I had to change some of the rights, using `chmod 755 /usr/share/kwin/effects/kwin4_effect_grayscale/` and then 
`find /usr/share/kwin/effects/kwin4_effect_login/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +`.