# KWin: Toggle grayscale KDE destop effect with script

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kwin

I'm very new to KDE (running Kubuntu 18.10) and want to be able to quickly toggle grayscale through the terminal. I can make the script to do this but I don't know what to call to toggle the Desktop Effect.

Currently I'm using the extension described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076025/how-can-i-get-a-grayscale-effect-in-kubuntu-18-04-using-kwin) from [this](https://github.com/murat-cileli/kwin-grayscale-effect) Github reop.  Everything works great, the only problem is that I want to quickly switch to grayscale instead of going into `System Settings` > `Desktop Behavior` >`Desktop Effects` and click `Apply`.  This is way to many steps for me to use more than once or twice a day.

My question is what command do I call to toggle this from the command line so I can write a script to do this?

I'm looking at the qdbus and trying something like:

```
qdbus org.kde.KWwin /Effects toggleEffect Grayscale
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that quirk was present but everything works fine once I applied the Desktop Effects with Grayscale off and on.  I'm reading up on how KWin extension work so might get somewhere.

Comment: When you toggle the Grayscale effect, changes are written to *~/.config/kwinrc* in the *[Plugins]* section. Specifically, toggling changes *kwin4_effect_grayscaleEnabled=false* to *kwin4_effect_grayscaleEnabled=true* or vice versa. If you **don't** use the default GUI, but use the command line (or a script) using `kwriteconfig5 --file ~/.config/kwinrc --group Plugins --key kwin4_effect_grayscaleEnabled "false"` (or "true"), you need to reload KWin to effect the change. `kwin_x11 --replace & disown` reloads KWin but may make the system unstable! There maybe a better way of which I'm not aware.

Comment: In short, my experience of not using the default GUI isn't a happy one!

Comment: There's also `qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin reconfigure` which I found [here](https://zren.github.io/kde/) but haven't tried. *zren* is a KDE developer.

Comment: Thanks.  A combination of kwriteconfig and /KWin reconfigure worked well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't deserve an answer, but I don't have the reputation to comment.

I'm trying to automate grayscale toggling via a shortcut too, and sometimes the set:

```
kwriteconfig5 --file ~/.config/kwinrc --group Plugins --key kwin4_effect_grayscaleEnabled "false"
qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin reconfigure
```

doesn't work (effect is not disabling, even if visibly unchecked in the settings).

So I just add an extra line:

```
qdbus org.kde.KWin /Compositor suspend && qdbus org.kde.KWin /Compositor resume
```

(it reloads the compositor, the same as doing "alt+shift+F12" twice)

And this allows to avoid the heavy `kwin_x11 --replace` solution, so I think it's better (but I'm absolutely no expert here).

(Note that I had to add a `sleep 0.2` in between the two lines too, otherwise the grayscale disabling didn't work unless I triggered the whole thing a second time)

Answer (score 1):

If you are still interested in the DBUS answer, which its a bit less complicated, you can try this:

```
#Enable the Effect:
qdbus --literal org.kde.KWin /Effects org.kde.kwin.Effects.loadEffect kwin4_effect_grayscale

#Disable the Effect:
qdbus --literal org.kde.KWin /Effects org.kde.kwin.Effects.unloadEffect kwin4_effect_grayscale

#Toggle the Effect state:
qdbus --literal org.kde.KWin /Effects org.kde.kwin.Effects.toggleEffect kwin4_effect_grayscale
```

Comment: loadEffect isn't "get the effect status," it enables it. It also returns true if it loaded it or false if it was already loaded.

There's also org.kde.kwin.Effects.unloadEffect to disable it.