# KDE plugins installation path

Tags: software-installation, kde, plugins

Where are KDE plasma plugins (e.g KWin effects , blur) located ? (i.e those which are installed via package manager or by default)

Comment: Consulting [http://userbase.kde.org][1] reveals /lib64/kde3/module is the designated location. Since that documentation https://userbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/KDE_Filesystem_Hierarchy is outdated, suggest you follow KDE's own procedure from https://community.kde.org/Get_Involved/Issue_Reporting and report this to https://bugs.kde.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/usr/share/kwin/effects/
```

On my Kubuntu 18.04:

```
$ ls /usr/share/kwin/effects/ -1
desktopgrid
kwin4_effect_dialogparent
kwin4_effect_eyeonscreen
kwin4_effect_fade
kwin4_effect_fadedesktop
kwin4_effect_frozenapp
kwin4_effect_grayscale ***
kwin4_effect_login
kwin4_effect_logout
kwin4_effect_maximize
kwin4_effect_morphingpopups
kwin4_effect_scalein
kwin4_effect_translucency
kwin4_effect_windowaperture
presentwindows
$
```

*** For `kwin4_effect_grayscale` which is a downloaded plugin, see [How can I get a grayscale effect in Kubuntu 18.04 using KWin?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1076025/248158).

(I don't know why there is use of `kwin4`. The use of `kwin4` continues even in Plasma 5.18.3 used by Kubuntu 20.04 and in openSUSE Tumbleweed 20200314.)

> Also searching plugins by name in suspected directories like "/usr" doesn't yield any useful results

True. Getting the actual name isn't obvious from looking at `kcmshell5 kcmkwineffects`.